# How to implement a list that looks like a table and has a scrollbar (image included)

Tags: html, css

How can I implement a list that looks like this. As you can see there are 3 columns equally divided and there is a vertical scrollbar.

[image: list]

Comment: You need to post the CSS and HTML code that you've already attempted to use to make this work so we can help you get it the way you want it.

Comment: Do you want that in one div, e.g. what is seen on the image is basically one div within a page?

Comment: Did you consider using a specific framework? Where does the data comes from? If you want pure CSS, Dan's solution below would work.

Comment: @SilverQuettier I get this data from a backend service. What do you mean a specific framework?

Comment: I was referring to things like [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) (which is simple but may not offer you something like what you're searching) or the more complex and resource-intensive [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid) which is a longtime favorite of mine... If you have a complex, application-server-based backend, you may want to look into UI frameworks. If it's just two PHP pages, don't bother :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>credit</li>
<li>card processing</li>
<li>credit report</li>
...
<li>etc</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{width:600px;height:100px; overflow-y:scroll;}
li{float:left;width:192px;border:1px solid black;}
li:nth-chilr(n+3){border-top:0xp;}
li:nth-child(3n+2){border-width:1px 0px 1px 0px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d72BN/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would give the `ul` a fixed width and height and give it `overflow-y:auto;` (or `scroll`). Then I'd make the `li`s all `display: inline-block` and `width:32%`. I'd also leave the closing tags off the `li`s so that there's no unwanted whitespace between them.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQrUt/)